# Is minimal polynomial of field of rational numbers and field of real numbers are same? Why?

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Is minimal polynomial of field of  rational numbers and field of real numbers are same?    Why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depends.

The minimal polynomial of the imaginary unit $i\in\Bbb C$ is $x^2+1$, which is a polynomial over the rationals and the reals.

But the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 2\in\Bbb R$ is $x^2-2$ over the rationals and $x-\sqrt 2$ over the reals.

Answer (score 0):

Note that over the field $\mathbb{R}$ of the real numbers irreducible polynomials have degree $\leq2$.

On the other hand over the field $\mathbb{Q}$ of rational numbers you can find irreducible polynomials of any degree, meaning that the degree of irreducible polynomials is not bounded. For instance, if $p$ is a prime number the polynomial
$$
1+X+X^2+\cdots+X^{p-1}
$$
is notoriously irreducible.

This answers your questions because irreducible polynomials are the minimal polynomials of their roots.

Comment: Or an even simpler example, $X^n-2$ by Eisenstein.

Comment: @J.G. Certainly.